# Aggregating Categorical Variables with Pandas Groupby, agg, and sorting

Tags: pandas, count, aggregate

I am unable to sort the 'count' column from aggregated categorical variable

df_perCity

```
.groupby(['City','Complaint Type'])['Complaint Type']
.agg(['count'])
.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False))
.sort_values(by='City')
```

I tried searching everywhere but the closest I think would be to add a new column. I prefer to not add a column to keep data integrity.

If I unstack it, the column 'count' would effectively transform into the column axis and sorting will not make sense by City, by Complaint Type.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: why are you using `apply` instead of just `sort_values`? and then you want to `sort_index(level=0)` to sort by `city`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I just realized that! It must have been due to so many times I have tried so many combinations of how to make it work. You just solved it! I have removed it now and just added sort_values(by=['City', 'count'], ascending=False). I swear it did not work with these before hence i went crazy looking for the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
df_perCity
.groupby(['City','Complaint Type'])['Complaint Type']
.agg(['count'])
.sort_values(by=['City','count'], ascending=False)
```

[image]

Or you could do:

```
.sort_values(['City','count'], asending=[True,False])
```

For those seeking the answer here it is thanks to @josh Friedlander for pointing out the mistake.